# Review of my question ban on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, post-ban

I was auto-banned from posting new questions in Stack Overflow. I have earnestly tried to improve my questions. Please review them once more. The questions are listed below:

1. [Program unresponsive on launching sub-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504736/swing-application-and-condition-java)
2. [Java thread join 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218307/java-thread-join-3)
3. [refreshing a panel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225527/refreshing-a-panel-in-java)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368172/server-side-gui

Comment: One other tip: improve the good ones as well if at all possible. It's not just improving the downvoted ones that can help. Oh, and please give your questions a descriptive title. "swing application and condition java" doesn't tell me anything about the problem you're going to ask us about. Nor does "java thread join 3" or "server side gui"

Comment: @Bart : Will positively look into that.Thx.

Comment: It looks like a large part of the reason is that you aren't showing any attempt at debugging the problem yourself or explaining where you think the issue is. Many users on SO downvote questions that seem to be asking for someone to do their work for them without showing any attempt at effort themselves ahead of time. In addition to improving the questions, you may want to try to include more explanation of what you've done to try to debug the problem yourself, and where you think the error is.

Comment: (Also be wary of the "meta effect", and note that we cannot just go in and lift the ban)

Comment: Thanks to all.The ban is lifted in no time.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will still be on the edge. So keep improving, and keep contributing good content. If you do, you'll move away from that edge. If you don't, you may fall back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your questions have all been markedly improved and the result of the additional attention given to those questions has already led to significant upvotes on them. Therefore the following should be considered "ideas to make them even better" rather than significant problems with them.

## Titles

You titles at present are more like subject headers. Try to make then a succinct statement of the problem. So that a person reading the title has a good idea if they can answer the question without even opening it. Additionally there is no need to put the language in the title (unless it fits "naturally" into the title") since the tags system does that for you. For example the following title changes might be an improvement

[Java thread join 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218307/java-thread-join-3) -->Result of child threads never returned to parent thread
[Server Side Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368172/server-side-gui) --> What is the purpose of ServerLaunchManager in Server Side GUI?

## Specific questions

#### [Program unresponsive on launching sub-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504736/swing-application-and-condition-java)

This question is much better now, it includes what the problem is and a short program to reproduce it. This question got a +1 from me and I have nothing more to add.

#### [Java thread join 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218307/java-thread-join-3)

What exactly you mean by "suspended" isn't completely clear. I would prefer a more clear cut explanation, but its fairly easy to infer your meaning. In its current form I certainly wouldn't downvote this

#### [refreshing a panel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225527/refreshing-a-panel-in-java)

Ignoring title capitalisation issues I again find nothing objectionable in this question. +1.

#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368172/server-side-gui

The question itself (with the exception of the title as discussed) seems good, although it took me a little while to find the actual question; in cases like this it can help to include **"Background:"** and **"Question:"** sections. However; it may not be a good fit for stack overflow. More conceptual questions usually find a better home on the "[programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)" site